# recursive number that separates each digit from integer number in java

Tags: java, recursion

I want to separate each digit of a number by a recursive function. I am trying the following function:

```
private static void print( int n ){
    print( n/10, n%10 );
}

private static int print( int n, int ld ){
    if( n < 10 ) return n;
    int digit = n % 10;
    int first = print( n/10, ld );
    System.out.println( digit );
    return first;
}
```

But it does not work. Can anyone help me how can I change the above function to achieve my outcome ?

input : 12345
output: 1 2 3 4 5

I want to do this by a recursive function

Comment: please extend your question with a clear example of input and expected output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print digits in correct order.

```java
    private static void print( int n ){

        int t = (int)Math.floor(n / 10);

        if (t > 0) {
            print(t);
            System.out.println( n % (t * 10) ); 
        }
        else 
            System.out.println( n );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for creating two functions 
From the first function result, you are not using where you have made a call for `print(arg, arg)`

just add terminate condition when the result gets 0

```
private static void print( int n ){
        if (n == 0)  return;

        int digit = n%10;
        System.out.println(digit);

        print( n/10  );
    }
```

Comment: I do not want to print each digit of number in reverse

Comment: Then what is your expected result? you haven't mentioned that!